# An Unusual Amount Of Help

Tags: chess, optimization

Another day, another helpmate to solve!

[image]

Given that White moves first and to help Black checkmate White, find the least number of moves needed such that Black mates:

-With a queen

-With a rook

-With a bishop

-With a knight

-And while capturing only four pieces

The Black pawn on Black's first rank moves like a normal Black pawn moves downward.

Good luck to all solvers!

Comment: You can only give one check mark. Does it not make more sense to split these multiple scenarios up into multiple questions?

Comment: Note that it is standard in helpmate to have Black play the first move and White mate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seeing as there is no answer yet, somehow, here is what I have leftover from my personal notes.

With a queen and rook:

> 1. Kb8 hxg7 2. Ka8 gxf6 3. Ngh8 fxe5 4. Neg6 exd4 5. N8g7 dxc3 6. Nde8 cxd2 7. Ndf6 dxc1=Q 8. Nb6d5 Qxc2 9. Nb5d4 Qxc4 10. Na7b5 Qxc5 11. Rcd6 Qxc7 12. Ra7 Qxc8#

With a rook, four captures only:

> 1. Kb8 hxg7 2. Ngh8 g6 3. Nfg7 gxh5 4. Nh4g6 h4 5. N3f5 hxg3 6. Nf1e3 gxf2 7. N2h4 f1=R 8. Nca8 Rf2 9. Ngh5 Rf1 10. Nfg7 Rf2 11. Ne7f5 Rf1 12. Re7 Rf2 13. Kc7 Rf1 14. Kd7 Rf2 15. N6c7 Rf1 16. Ke6 Rf2 17. Ned7 Rf1 18. Nb8 Rf2 19. Ke5 Rf1 20. Nf4e6 Rf2 21. Kf4 Rf1 22. Ng4e5 Rf2 23. Kg4 Rf1 24. Nh3f4 Rf2 25. Kh3 Rf1 26. Ned7 Rf2 27. Nf7e5 Rf1 28. Rf7 Rf2 29. Nfg4 Rf1 30. Rf6 Rf2 31. Nfe7 Rf1 32. Rf5 Rf2 33. Ngf7 Rf1 34. Rg5 Rf2 35. Ng4f6 Rf1 36. Rg3 Rf2 37. Nd6f5 Rf1 38. Rd6 Rf2 39. Nd4c6 Rf1 40. Ne6d4 Rf2 41. Re6 Rf1 42. Ne4d6 Rf2 43. Nfe4 Rf1 44. Rf6 Rf2 45. Nf4e6 Rf1 46. Ngf4 Rf2 47. Rfg6 Rf1 48. R6g4 Rf2 49. N3g5 Rf1 50. Nh2f3 Rf2 51. N5g6 Rf1 52. Nf3e5 Rf2 53. Nh5f6 Rh2#

With a bishop, and also four captures only:

> 1. Kb8 hxg7 2. Nca8 gxh6 3. Kc7 hxg5 4. N8g7 gxf4 5. Nde8 fxe3 6. Kd6 exd2 7. N4h6 dxe1=B 8. Neg4 Bxc3 9. Ke5 Bxd4+ 10. Kf4 Bxc5 11. Nf3g5 Bxb4 12. Ng4e5 Be1 13. Rg4 Bb4 14. Kg3 Bc5 15. Rf3 Bxg1 16. Nd5f4 Bc5 17. Nfd2 Bb4 18. Ndc5 Bxd2 19. Ne2c3 Be3 20. Rd2 Bg1 21. Rdf2 Bxh2#

With a knight:

> This can be done in 11 move, but I have lost the moves.